# Динамическое получение данных от checkbox

Tags: php, post, checkbox

Доброго времени суток!
Есть файл Check_boil_switchs.php, который выполняется каждую секунду

В этом файле находиться алгоритм чтения данных из БД MySQL с последующим выставлением переключателей в состояния "0" или "1" в зависимости от значения переменных, полученных при чтении БД.

```
<var>
  <?php if ($row["Manual_control"]==1):?>
  <input id="switch1" class="switch" name="switch1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked  />
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if ($row["Manual_control"]==0):?>
  <input id="switch1" class="switch" name="switch1" type="checkbox" value="0" />
  <?php endif; ?>
  <label for="switch1">Ручное управление</label><br><br> 
</var>
```

Это все работает. При загрузке в первую же секунду переключатели выставляются правильно и если я меняю какой-то, то в течении секунды он возвращается в положение исходя из значения данных БД.

Назрела вторая задача - между обновлениями переключателей обработать изменения через тот же $_POST и записать в БД новые значения.
Как записать знаю, а вот как обработать правильно $_POST - не знаю.

Пробую такую конструкцию, но вижу, что переменная switch1 имеет пустое значение

```
<form action="Check_boil_switchs.php #change_switch" method="post">


<div id="change_switch">
<?php
// проверяем состояние данных перед сравнением
echo  "Manual_control ="; echo $row["Manual_control"]; 
?>
<br> </br>
<?php
echo "switch1 = "; echo $_POST['switch1'];
?>
<br> </br>
<?php
if($_POST['switch1'] != $row["Manual_control"])
{
echo "Состояние Manual_control изменено, пишем в базу!";
//$row["Manual_control"]=!$row["Manual_control"];
//Функция записи новой строки таблицы в БД
}
 else 
{
echo "Manual_control без изменений";
//Ничего не делаем
}
?>
</div> 

<var>
  <?php if ($row["Manual_control"]==1):?>
  <input id="switch1" class="switch" name="switch1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked  />
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if ($row["Manual_control"]==0):?>
  <input id="switch1" class="switch" name="switch1" type="checkbox" value="0" />
  <?php endif; ?>
  <label for="switch1">Ручное управление</label><br><br> 
</var>
```

И соответственно if ВСЕГДА уходит на "Состояние Manual_control изменено, пишем в базу!"

Может action неправильно прописан?

Comment: Отправляете изменения тем же ajax`ом и обрабатываете в скрипте как и всегда обрабатывали пост запросы. Опишите более детально, возможно будут идеи.

Comment: А зачем вы вообще в `action` пишете: `#change_switch`? Как это `php` должен контролировать? Как он интересно должен понять, что это `id` - вашего `div` ? Это же не `js`.Да и вообще, пора бы избавлять от `action`. Да и код, ужасный, если честно.

Comment: Может у вас есть кусок кода, который обрабатывает ckeckbox при нажатии и записывает в БД? Я только начал с этим разбираться и пока не могу понять как правильно сформировать POST для отправки всех chekbox при нажатии на любой. И соответственно как потом этот пост разобрать, на PHP, чтобы в нужные переменные таблицы уложить.